# Need specific URL in angular 5

Tags: node.js, angular, url, angular5, angular6

(NodeJS 9.4 and Angular 5).

```
// In app.js I have,
app.use('/', login);
app.use('/app', application);

// in the route file application.js, I have,
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render("application/index");            
});

// in angular 5 I have
{
    path      : 'angular_path',
    component : AngularComponent
},{
    path      : '**',
    redirectTo: 'angular_path'
}
```

Now when I enter the URL 
    `localhost:3000/app`
it takes me to 
   `localhost:3000/#/angular_path`

All these are working perfectly fine for me,
but now when I refresh the page, it sends me back to the login page,
That's why I need the URL to be
    `localhost:3000/app/#/angular_path`

I need the word  `/app/` before the angular route.

||HELP||

Comment: I think you can use node.js to auto-redirect to '/app' if the user was logged in.

Comment: Ya, I have thought about this also, it's going to be my last option if couldn't find any other way.

Answer (score 0):

try this code to set prefix in the URL.

**Add this code in the app.js**

```
var router = express.Router();
app.use('/app', router);
```

Comment: Its already there, but the angular is removing the /app from the url.